# How to implement SSR for Material UI's media queries in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I can't follow the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#server-side-rendering) of implementing Material UI's media queries because it's specified for a plain React app and I'm using NextJs. Specifically, I don't know where to put the following code that the documentation specifies:

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import parser from 'ua-parser-js';
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function handleRender(req, res) {
  const deviceType = parser(req.headers['user-agent']).device.type || 'desktop';
  const ssrMatchMedia = query => ({
    matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
      // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
      width: deviceType === 'mobile' ? '0px' : '1024px',
    }),
  });

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={{
        props: {
          // Change the default options of useMediaQuery
          MuiUseMediaQuery: { ssrMatchMedia },
        },
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>,
  );

  // …
}
```

The reason that I want to implement this is because I use media queries to conditionally render certain components, like so:

```
const xs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'))
...
return(
  {xs ?
     <p>Small device</p>
  :
     <p>Regular size device</p>
  }
)
```

I know that I could use Material UI's `Hidden` but I like this approach where the media queries are variables with a state because I also use them to conditionally apply css.

I'm already using `styled components` and Material UI's styles with SRR. This is my `_app.js`

```
  import NextApp from 'next/app'
  import React from 'react'
  import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

  const theme = { 
    primary: '#4285F4'
  }

  export default class App extends NextApp {
    componentDidMount() {
      const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side')
      if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode)
        jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles)
    }

    render() {
      const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <style jsx global>
            {`  
              body {
                margin: 0;
              }   
              .tui-toolbar-icons {
                background: url(${require('~/public/tui-editor-icons.png')});
                background-size: 218px 188px;
                display: inline-block;
              }   
            `}  
          </style>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )   
    }
  }
```

And this is my `_document.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

import NextDocument from 'next/document'

import { ServerStyleSheet as StyledComponentSheets } from 'styled-components'
import { ServerStyleSheets as MaterialUiServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles'

export default class Document extends NextDocument {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const styledComponentSheet = new StyledComponentSheets()
    const materialUiSheets = new MaterialUiServerStyleSheets()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props =>
            styledComponentSheet.collectStyles(
              materialUiSheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
            )   
        })  

      const initialProps = await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx)

      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: [
          <React.Fragment key="styles">
            {initialProps.styles}
            {materialUiSheets.getStyleElement()}
            {styledComponentSheet.getStyleElement()}
          </React.Fragment>
        ]   
      }   
    } finally {
      styledComponentSheet.seal()
    }   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="es">
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa|Open+Sans&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First a caveat -- I do not currently have any experience using SSR myself, but I have [deep knowledge of Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/material-ui/topusers) and I think that with the code you have included in your question and the Next.js documentation, I can help you work through this.

You are already showing in your `_app.js` how you are setting your `theme` into your styled-components `ThemeProvider`. You will also need to set a theme for the Material-UI ThemeProvider and you need to choose between two possible themes based on device type.

First define the two themes you care about. The two themes will use different implementations of `ssrMatchMedia` -- one for mobile and one for desktop.

```
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery';
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const mobileSsrMatchMedia = query => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
    // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
    width: "0px"
  })
});
const desktopSsrMatchMedia = query => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
    // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
    width: "1024px"
  })
});

const mobileMuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Change the default options of useMediaQuery
    MuiUseMediaQuery: { ssrMatchMedia: mobileSsrMatchMedia }
  }
});
const desktopMuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Change the default options of useMediaQuery
    MuiUseMediaQuery: { ssrMatchMedia: desktopSsrMatchMedia }
  }
});
```

In order to choose between the two themes, you need to leverage the user-agent from the request. Here's where my knowledge is very light, so there may be minor issues in my code here. I think you need to use `getInitialProps` (or `getServerSideProps` in Next.js 9.3 or newer). `getInitialProps` receives the [context object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object) from which you can get the HTTP request object (`req`). You can then use `req` in the same manner as in the Material-UI documentation example to determine the device type.

Below is an approximation of what I think `_app.js` should look like (not executed, so could have minor syntax issues, and has some guesses in `getInitialProps` since I have never used Next.js):

```
import NextApp from "next/app";
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import mediaQuery from "css-mediaquery";
import parser from "ua-parser-js";

const theme = {
  primary: "#4285F4"
};

const mobileSsrMatchMedia = query => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
    // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
    width: "0px"
  })
});
const desktopSsrMatchMedia = query => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
    // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
    width: "1024px"
  })
});

const mobileMuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Change the default options of useMediaQuery
    MuiUseMediaQuery: { ssrMatchMedia: mobileSsrMatchMedia }
  }
});
const desktopMuiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Change the default options of useMediaQuery
    MuiUseMediaQuery: { ssrMatchMedia: desktopSsrMatchMedia }
  }
});

export default class App extends NextApp {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    // I'm guessing on this line based on your _document.js example
    const initialProps = await NextApp.getInitialProps(ctx);
    // OP's edit: The ctx that we really want is inside the function parameter "ctx"
    const deviceType =
      parser(ctx.ctx.req.headers["user-agent"]).device.type || "desktop";
    // I'm guessing on the pageProps key here based on a couple examples
    return { pageProps: { ...initialProps, deviceType } };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode)
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider
        theme={
          pageProps.deviceType === "mobile" ? mobileMuiTheme : desktopMuiTheme
        }
      >
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <style jsx global>
            {`
              body {
                margin: 0;
              }
              .tui-toolbar-icons {
                background: url(${require("~/public/tui-editor-icons.png")});
                background-size: 218px 188px;
                display: inline-block;
              }
            `}
          </style>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited this but now I see it's not applied inmediately: When initializing deviceType what works is `const deviceType = parser(ctx.ctx.req.headers["user-agent"]).device.type || "desktop";`

Comment: @ArturoCuya Strange. Based on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) I would expect it to be just `ctx.req` rather than `ctx.ctx.req` but as long as it works....

Comment: Cool great answer. But dont do this in your `_app.js` file with getInitialprops. If you do that then next js will server render all your pages that mean automatic static optimization wont work.

Comment: How to implement this for NextJS /app directory

Answer (score 2):

### MUI v5

You'd need two packages,

1. [ua-parser-js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) - to parse the user agent device type. With this we can know whether a user is on mobile or desktop.
2. [css-mediaquery](https://github.com/ericf/css-mediaquery) - to provide an implementation of `matchMedia` to the `useMediaQuery` hook we have used everywhere.

```
// _app.js
import NextApp from 'next/app';
import parser from 'ua-parser-js'; // 1.
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery'; // 2.

import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';


const App = ({ Component, pageProps, deviceType }) => {
  const ssrMatchMedia = (query) => ({
    matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
      // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
      width: deviceType === 'mobile' ? '0px' : '1024px',
    }),
  });

  const theme = createTheme({
    // your MUI theme configuration goes here
    components: {
      MuiUseMediaQuery: {
        defaultProps: {
          ssrMatchMedia,
        },
      },
    }
  });


  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ); 
};

App.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  let deviceType;

  if (context.ctx.req) {
    deviceType = parser(context.ctx.req.headers['user-agent']).device.type || 'desktop';
  }

  return {
    ...NextApp.getInitialProps(context),
    deviceType,
  };
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have an answer for new app router?

Comment: @YourNeighbor Haven't worked with the app router yet. But the implementation should be simple if you know where to put the client and server logic.

Comment: Does this solution work with SSG

Answer (score 0):

For nextjs > 13.0 (app router)

theme.tsx

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery'; // 2.
// Create a theme instance.

const ssrMatchMedia = (deviceType: string) => (query: string) => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
    width: deviceType === 'mobile' ? '0px' : '1024px',
  })
})

const theme = (deviceType: string) => createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiUseMediaQuery: {
      defaultProps: {
        ssrMatchMedia: ssrMatchMedia(deviceType)
      }
    }
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#3D56F0',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 400,
      md: 740,
      lg: 1000,
      xl: 1436,
      xxl: 1700,
    },
  },
});
export default theme;

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: true;
    sm: true;
    md: true;
    lg: true;
    xl: true;
    xxl: true;
  }
}
```

ThemeRegistry.tsx

```
'use client';
import theme from '@/config/theme';
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v13-appRouter';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

export default function ThemeRegistry({ children, deviceType }: { children: ReactNode, deviceType: string }) {
    const mainTheme = theme(deviceType)
    return (
        <AppRouterCacheProvider options={{ key: 'mui' }}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                {children}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
    );
}
```

layout.tsx (root)

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
import parser from 'ua-parser-js';

export default function Layout(props: {
    children: React.ReactNode,
}) {
    const headersList = headers()
    const referer = headersList.get('user-agent')
    const parsed = parser(referer?.toString()).device.type || 'desktop'
    return (
        <>
            <html lang="pt-BR">
                <body>
                    <ServerAuthProvider>
                        <ThemeRegistry deviceType={parsed}>
                            {props.children}
                        </ThemeRegistry>
                    </ServerAuthProvider>
                    <Analytics />
                </body>
            </html>
        </>
    )
}
```