# How to implement Material UI's `useMediaQuery` in NextJs(13.4) `/app` route to avoid flash?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I'm currently working on a Next.js project and utilizing the 'app' router to set up a common layout across all pages. To handle responsive design, I'm using Material-UI (MUI) and its useMediaQuery hook. However, I'm encountering an issue where there's a brief flash screen of the mobile version on the desktop device during the initial second of the render when load a page.

Here's an overview of my setup:

1. MUI with NextJS `13.4.4` `/app` route.
2. Using Client Component By `"use client";` directives of NextJS.

Here is the Code:

```
 "use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { NextLinkComposed } from "../Link";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { drawerWidth } from "@/utils/constraints";
import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Drawer,
  Box,
  useMediaQuery,
  InputAdornment,
  OutlinedInput,
} from "@mui/material";
import {
  GroupsOutlined as GroupsIcon,
  DashboardOutlined as DashboardIcon,
  Search as SearchIcon,
} from "@mui/icons-material";

export default function SideBar({
  handleDrawerToggle,
  drawerOpen,
}: {
  handleDrawerToggle: () => void;
  drawerOpen: boolean;
}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matchUpMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("md"));

  const container =
    typeof window !== undefined ? () => window.document.body : undefined;

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const filteredItems = SideBarItems.filter((item) =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  );

  const drawer = (
    <Box
      component="div"
      sx={{
        marginTop: { md: "66px", xs: "12px" },
        paddingLeft: "16px",
        paddingRight: "16px",
      }}
    >
      <Box>
        <OutlinedInput
          size="small"
          id="input-search-header"
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
          sx={{
            borderRadius: 3,
          }}
          placeholder="Search"
          startAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <SearchIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          }
          aria-describedby="search-helper-text"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "weight" }}
        />
      </Box>
      <List sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
        {filteredItems.map((item, index) => {
          const Icon = item.icon;
          return (
            <ListItem disablePadding key={index}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{ borderRadius: 3 }}
                component={NextLinkComposed}
                to={{
                  pathname: item.path,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Icon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
  return (
    <Box
      component="nav"
      sx={{ flexShrink: { md: 0 }, width: matchUpMd ? drawerWidth : "auto" }}
      aria-label="mailbox folders"
    >
      <Drawer
        container={container}
        variant={matchUpMd ? "persistent" : "temporary"}
        open={drawerOpen}
        onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
        }}
        sx={{
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            background: theme.palette.background.default,
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            borderRight: "none",
          },
        }}
      >
        {drawer}
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
  );
}

const SideBarItems = [
  {
    name: "Dashboard",
    path: "/dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
  },
  { name: "Users", path: "/user", icon: GroupsIcon },
];
```

PLEASE HELP!
Thank You.

Comment: Do you have answer now?

Comment: I saw another issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510890/how-to-implement-ssr-for-material-uis-media-queries-in-nextjs/73372426?noredirect=1#comment135800107_73372426

Comment: @YourNeighbor But that issue is for /page dir in nextJS. I'm asking for /app directory. Which is a completely new architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround approach for this case (I use app router & SSG rendering). Based on this article from MUI official docs (https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/next-js-app-router/#next-js-and-react-server-components).

This approach need to set a state in localStorage as **deviceWidth** in the first load. Because localStorage is synchronous, it doesn't have any blocking.

**ThemeProvider.tsx**

```
"use client";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import React from "react";
import mediaQuery from "css-mediaquery";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiUseMediaQuery: {
      defaultProps: {
        ssrMatchMedia: (query) => ({
          matches: mediaQuery.match(query, {
            // The estimated CSS width of the browser.
            width: localStorage.getItem("deviceWidth") || 1200, // Add this default prop
          }),
        }),
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function ThemeRegistry(props: any) {
  const { options, children } = props;

  const [{ cache, flush }] = React.useState(() => {
    const cache = createCache(options);
    cache.compat = true;
    const prevInsert = cache.insert;
    let inserted: string[] = [];
    cache.insert = (...args) => {
      const serialized = args[1];
      if (cache.inserted[serialized.name] === undefined) {
        inserted.push(serialized.name);
      }
      return prevInsert(...args);
    };
    const flush = () => {
      const prevInserted = inserted;
      inserted = [];
      return prevInserted;
    };
    return { cache, flush };
  });

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const names = flush();
    if (names.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    let styles = "";
    for (const name of names) {
      styles += cache.inserted[name];
    }
    return (
      <style
        key={cache.key}
        data-emotion={`${cache.key} ${names.join(" ")}`}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: styles,
        }}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

**layout.tsx**

```
import ThemeRegistry from "./ThemeRegistry";
  import "./styles.css";

  export default function RootLayout({
    children,
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }) {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
          <ThemeRegistry options={{ key: "mui" }}>{children}</ThemeRegistry>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can you use mui hidden component approach [see here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#hidden).You can create two seperate drawers and hide them acc to breakpoints using sx props.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).